# How to sync the dependency of package json in npm

Tags: node.js, npm

In my case，i use `npm install moduleName -save` to install a module ,but after npm notice that it is install complete,the package.json will not be add dependencies of the module;
Is there any solution to sync from module to dependencies;
Thanks at first

Comment: You're missing one more dash before save

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `npm install moduleName --save` (2 '-')

Comment: thanks it is work.By the way. how can i sync the module which already be installed  to package.json

Comment: what do you mean by sync? update to latest version? Just do `npm install moduleName@latest --save`

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use one -s. Here is the quote from the npm documentation:

> As of version 2.0.0 you can provide a path to a local directory that
>   contains a package. Local paths can be saved using `npm install -S` or
>   `npm install --save`, using any of these forms:

So if you wanted to install lodash you could use:

`npm install lodash --save`

or:

`npm install -S lodash`